# How to get all liked tweets by a user using twitter API?

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I am using a python twitter bot to follow and like (favorite) tweets with a given string in them, I want to check if I didn't already follow these users and if those tweets weren't already liked.

I found this function :

```
my_bot.TWITTER_CONNECTION.favorites.list(count=1000)
```

with `TWITTER_CONNECTION` a twitter instance with my credentials

unfortunately I found in the docs that I can only get 200 max recent liked tweets. how can I get them all (1000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned the max number of tweets that can be retrieved is 200 but there is another workaround using the same function with the argument `max_id`

```
 favorites = my_bot.TWITTER_CONNECTION.favorites.list(count=200, max_id=last_id)
```

with `last_id` is the last tweet I got when running this command first, and so on this can be inserted in a loop